# Avoid Keyboard on items on the Bottom - React Native

Tags: styles, react-native, react-native-ios

I have this React Native proyect (with Expo), and i have 2 buttons on the bottom of the container. When i open the keyboard to write something, those items come up with the keyboard. ¿How can i avoid that?

[image]

[image]

Here's the container code ->

```
render() {
    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1}}>
        <Text style={styles.titulo}>Nueva Tarjeta</Text>
        <View style={{  flex: 1}}>
          <CreditCardInput
            requiresName={true}
            allowScroll={true}
            labels={{
              name: "Nombre del titular",
              number: "Número de tarjeta",
              expiry: "Venc",
              cvc: "CVC",
            }}
            cardScale={1}
            labelStyle={{ fontFamily: "OpenSansRegular" }}
            placeholders={{
              name: "Juan Perez",
              number: "1234 1234 1234 1234",
              expiry: "MM/AA",
              cvc: "123",
            }}
            onChange={this._onChange}
          />
        </View>
        <View style={{ flexDirection: "row", alignSelf: "center", 
    justifyContent: 'flex-end', marginBottom: 10}}>
          <TouchableOpacity style={styles.botonVolver}>
            <Text style={styles.textoVolver}>Volver</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <TouchableOpacity style={styles.botonAceptar}>
            <Text style={styles.textoAceptar}>Aceptar</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1):

You could try using a [KeyboardAvoidingView](https://reactnative.dev/docs/keyboardavoidingview) with its `behavior` prop set to `'height'` on Android:

```
const screenHeight = Dimensions.get("window").height;

export default function App() {
  return (
    <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior="height" style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <View style={{ height: screenHeight - 75 }}>
        <Text style={styles.titulo}>Nueva Tarjeta</Text>
        <CreditCardInput
          requiresName={true}
          allowScroll={true}
          labels={{
            name: "Nombre del titular",
            number: "Número de tarjeta",
            expiry: "Venc",
            cvc: "CVC",
          }}
          cardScale={1}
          labelStyle={{ fontFamily: "OpenSansRegular" }}
          placeholders={{
            name: "Juan Perez",
            number: "1234 1234 1234 1234",
            expiry: "MM/AA",
            cvc: "123",
          }}
        />
      </View>
      <View
        style={{
          flexDirection: "row",
          alignSelf: "center",
          justifyContent: "flex-end",
          marginBottom: 10,
        }}
      >
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.botonVolver}>
          <Text style={styles.textoVolver}>Volver</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.botonAceptar}>
          <Text style={styles.textoAceptar}>Aceptar</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    </KeyboardAvoidingView>
  );
}
```

I also changed the height of the `View` that contains the `CreditCardInput` to be based on the screen height using `Dimensions`, because the transition was glitchy when `flex` was set on that `View`.

---

*Be sure to import `Dimensions` and `KeyboardAvoidingView` from `'react-native'`.*